# vim-ipython failed on Windows 7

Tags: python, windows, vim, ipython

I installed iPython by Anaconda on Windows 7. (There's no python installed previously). I can run ipython without problem.

Then I installed vim-ipython plugin. In vim, when I run

```
:IPython
```

I got this:

```
E492 Not an editor command.
```

I checked vim version:

```
:version
+python/dyn
```

I checked (in vim)

```
:python import sys
E370 Could not load python27.dll
```

Run python on cmd:

```
Python 2.7.5 |Anaconda 1.7.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  1 2013, 12:37:52) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Could you please tell me what is wrong with this installation?
Thank you.

Edit:
I tried (in Vim):

```
:echo has("python")
0
```

I get really confused!

Edit 2:
Thanks for everybody's help. I decide to build/compile vim 64-bit on windows. I've downloaded MinGW-w64, but don't know how to use it: I can't find 'make'. (I remember there's mingw-32-make in the 32 bit version, but none in the 64-bit version.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On windows for vim to find python DLL path to it must be present in `$PATH`. There are multiple ways to achieve this:

1. Editing registry. On wine I achieve this by adding a new path to the value of `PATH` key stored in`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment` by creating `path.reg` file:

   ```
   REGEDIT4

   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment]
   "PATH"="{put old value of %PATH% here};C:\\path\\to\\python\\dll"
   ```

   and running `regedit path.reg`, but I guess HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE is a bit of overkill and you need something under HKEY_CURRENT_USER. I am using it with wine (windows emulator) anyway so I do not care. You can launch `regedit` without arguments and try to find something there.
2. AFAIR there is a way to set `%PATH%` in a link file you use to launch vim.
3. Maybe just putting the following into the vimrc will work:

   ```
   let $PATH.=';C:\path\to\python\dll'
   ```

Note: none of the advices will work if vim was compiled with different python version support. Also if some configure flags (e.g. debugging support) differ between python from anaconda installer and python used by the whoever compiled vim error message should change. I do not know whether error message will change if vim is 32-bit and your python is 64-bit, but loading python will for sure fail in this case.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I checked path: there's c:/Anaconda/ (which contains python27.dll) in the path. I put let $PATH.=';C:/Anaconda' into my .vimrc, it doesn't work neither. I believe there's something wrong with the vim installation. Maybe I really need to compile it myself. Which compiler to use on Windows 64-bit? (I tried MinGW, however, it is a 32-bit compiler. )

Comment: @Nick ?! Quick searching for “MinGW 64 bit” found [this](http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/). Though compiling vim with Visual Studio should also work.

Comment: @Nick You also [seem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215651/how-to-compier-vim-64-bit-on-windows-using-mingw-64) to find this.

Answer (score 1):

Your troubleshooting output shows that your Vim is compiled with dynamically loaded Python (`+python/dyn`), but the error you get and `has('python') == 0` means that the Python interpreter cannot be successfully loaded. The IPython plugin probably has a guard clause that prevents its loading unless Python is available.

You need to fix the Python integration into Vim, either by making that DLL available to Vim (so that there'll be no errors and `has('python') == 1`), or (as a last resort) compiling Vim yourself.