# How to compile vim 64-bit on windows using MinGW-64?

Tags: vim, mingw-w64

I tried to compile vim 64-bit on windows. But I don't know how to use MinGW-64. There's a mingw-32-make in the 32-bit version, which I could use to build. But I didn't find any 'make' program in the 64-bit MinGW. Could you please tell me how to use mingw-64, or any tutorial I could follow?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not matter from which source `make` program comes, it only just must be able to execute the Makefile. To compile vim with MinGW with specific compiler and `Make_ming.mak` makefile I used to use the following:

1. Export environment variable `CC` set to the appropriate compiler (in my case it was 32-bit named `i686-pc-mingw32-gcc`).
2. Export environment variable `LD` set to the appropriate linker (in my case it was similar, but with `-ld` suffix in place of `-gcc`). Be sure they are found on `$PATH`: I am not sure what kind of escaping you should do to make makefile work so just avoid the necessity for escaping.
3. Export environment variable `prefix` pointing to the directory where mingw resides (in my case it was `/usr/i686-mingw32`: I am cross-compiling).
4. Export environment variable `vim_cv_toupper_broken` set to `yes`. I am not sure why I did this.
5. Finally run make:

   ```
   cd {path/to/vim/repository}/src
   make -f Make_ming.mak FEATURES=HUGE CROSS_COMPILE=i686-pc-mingw32- OPTIMIZE=SPEED VIMRUNTIMEDIR="C:\\vim73\\runtime" CROSS=yes ARCH=i686
   ```

   . You definitely do not need `CROSS_COMPILE` and `CROSS` options and `ARCH` should be probably omitted (or equal to `x86_64`). `VIMRUNTIMEDIR` should point to the place where you plan to install vim. Not sure about escaping though.

Exporting environment variables should be probably done with

```
set var=value
```

, e.g.

```
set CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc
```

(use actual name of the executable). If this does not work try moving them to the make command line:

```
make -f Make_ming.mak CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc LD=… …
```

.

And variables for python (should also be present on the command-line):

```
PYTHON="P:\\ath\\to\\directory\\with\\python" PYTHONINC="P:\\ath\\to\\directory\\with\\python\\header\\files" PYTHON_VER=27 PYTHON_VER_LONG=2.7.5
```

. (If using python msi installer `PYTHONINC` is `%PYTHON%\\include`. It is 90% some directory whose trailing path component is `include`. Should contain at least `Python.h` file.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and help. I'm not familiar with compile process. I tried again: 1.Installed TDM64-gcc. 2. Launch `ming32-make -f Make_ming.mak`. I got error: CPU you selected do not support X86-64 instruction set. I guess I should not use ming32-make. But you already point out that "it does not matter from which source make program comes." I really don't know what to do next.

Comment: @Nick Make is irrelevant, except for some weird cases with incompatible make implementations or makefiles using non-standard features. But just `make -f Make_ming.mak` is completely not enough. You must set the variables, either in environment or on command-line as I described. Most of them I do set on the command-line and cannot say whether these variables from environment will work. This looks like if you have not set correct `CC`. Maybe you need to set some `CFLAGS`, I am not sure. With just `make -f Make_ming.mak` you *for sure* will not get python support.

Comment: Thank you, ZyX. It might not be a good idea to compile traditional Linux software on windows. Maybe I should not use Windows in Linux's way. This problem has not solved. But I believe that follow your instruction step by step, it could be done. I plan to install a Windows/Linux dual-boot system. Put the programming work on Linux, and Photoshop related work on Windows. I hope this will be a practical approach.

Answer (score 0):

I just compiled VIM on MinGW and made a **[gist about it](https://gist.github.com/rpuntaie/8510218)**. I tried x86-64 (search for it), too, and with /etc/fstab changed to 64 it basically worked, just that my interpreters all were 32 and so it stopped there.

Comment: Thank you! I'm using Sublime Text editor on Windows now. You can give it a try as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set

```
ARCH=x86-64 in vim74/src/Make_ming.mak
```

and add option `CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc`, maybe it will be useful.